# Exception is stopping the program - how to prevent it

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
 void checkAge() {
    if (age < 18) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Access granted - You are old enough!");
    }
}
```

How can I prevent stopping my program if the age is less than 18?

Comment: You can catch the exception.

Comment: Or, instead of throwing an exception just display a friendly Message Box: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><b>ArithmeticException:</b><br><br><font color=red>Access denied</font> - You must be at least 18 years old.</html>", "Access Denied!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);`

Comment: well...  why do you stop the program if you don't want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the initial intuition is good, this is not what Exceptions are used for. Exceptions are generally used to signal errors that happen in the VM and should generally not be used to create logic flows.

The easiest way would be to turn your function into a boolean function

```java
boolean checkAge() {
    if (age < 18) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which can then be used in your `main` function as such

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int age = 20;
  if(checkAge(age)){
     System.out.println("Access granted - You are old enough!");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.");
  }
}
```

Obviously, the way you want to display it, (System.out, a message box) is up to you.

Another thing which should be noted in this case, is that the function is a little too simple to be abstracted away to an entire separate part of the code, and you should just compare directly in the main function, as such:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int age = 20;
  if(age >= 18){
     System.out.println("Access granted - You are old enough!");
  } else {
     System.out.println("Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.");
  }
}
```